# For Loop and Accumulator Pattern

Tags: python

An old legend has it that a wise man, when offered any reward he desired, requested that his first grandchild receive 1 coin, his second grandchild receive twice as many as the first, the third receive twice as many as the second, and so on. How many coins will the last grandchild receive?  How many coins will the grandchildren receive in all?  Your function should accept any number of grandchildren and return a statement addressing both questions. Ihave this so far

```
def grandchild_coins(number_of_grand_children):# Not finished
    Coins=1
    for grand_child in range(number_of_grand_children):
        Coins=Coins*2
    return ' Grand child' + str(grand_child) + ' ' + str(Coins) + ' Coins'
   grandchild_coins(10)
   Out[33]: ' Grand child9 1024 Coins'
```

how do i get it to list how much coins each grand child has ?

Thanks for the help guys

```
def grandchild_coins(number_of_grand_children):
              # initalizes coins to 1
    Coins=1
    total_coins=[]

# for grand_child in the range entered this code is ran
for grand_child in range(number_of_grand_children):

    # if the grand_child number is not 0 coins = coins*2
    if grand_child !=0:
        Coins=Coins*2
        # prints coins for each grand_child
    print ' Grand_Child' + str(grand_child)  + str( Coins)
    total_coins.append(Coins)

        # returns total amount of coins



return sum(total_coins) + ' Coins in total'
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not here to answer you assignments for you. Please include some more information about why your code doesn't work and what else you have tried.

Comment: JFTR the standard solution without a loop: `grandchild_coins = lambda x: 'Grandchild {} gets {} coins, all grandchildren {} coins'.format(x, 2**(x-1), 2**x-1)`

Comment: We are in our 2nd week of python that is too advanced based on what we have learned

Comment: @ Yep_It's_Me sorry grades were due soon and  I really needed help I didn't copy the code word for 4 words I modified it based on the help I recieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you return only last element in range (grand_child will equal 9 - range (10) means iteration from 0 to 9)
So, I would advice (Keeping close to your code):

```
def grandchild_coins(number_of_grand_children):
    Coins=1
    for grand_child in range(number_of_grand_children):
        if grand_child != 0: #where you need to keep 1 coinn for the first son
            Coins=Coins*2
        print(' Grand child' + str(grand_child + 1) + ' ' + str(Coins) + 'Coins')  
    return True

grandchild_coins(10)
```

And the output:

```
 Grand child1 1Coins
 Grand child2 2Coins
 Grand child3 4Coins
 Grand child4 8Coins
 Grand child5 16Coins
 Grand child6 32Coins
 Grand child7 64Coins
 Grand child8 128Coins
 Grand child9 256Coins
 Grand child10 512Coins
```

Comment: Thank you grades for class due tomorrow and this is the last problem I had

Comment: You are welcome. @Jason And if the answer helped, please, mark it as correct.

Comment: StackOverflow is not here to answer you assignments for you!

Answer (score 0):

You need a `print` statement at each iteration (instead of a `return` only at the end):

```
def grandchild_coins(number_of_grand_children):# Not finished
    Coins=1
    for grand_child in range(number_of_grand_children):
        Coins=Coins*2
        print 'Grand child' + str(grand_child) + ' ' + str(Coins) + ' Coins'
```

NOTE: this answers YOUR question, not what is asked in your homework...

And by the way you don't need for loops to solve this problem, a simple formula exists...

Comment: Isnt print going to give me the same output ?

Comment: why don't you try and see?

Comment: What do you mean ?  He must use a loop somehow, either with `yield` or with comprehension or with a list or with string, he still needs a loop

Comment: i did   grandchild_coins(10)
 grandchild_coins(10)
 Grand child9 1024